# Use of Simple Tense for future action without will & Shall

Tags: present-simple, future-time

> I Hope She forgives me.

Above sentence gives idea about future action of her without using Will, Shall etc. We can use Simple Present tense to describe future scheduled, planed action..

Considering above Rule can I construct Following Sentences?

> a) I send you that file.  (Gives Idea about my future planed action)
>
> b) Tomorrow I first go to the Temple and then to the Office. ( Future Plans)

Appreciate If I can have some more examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you hope for something, you are normally thinking about something that has not yet happened, but you would like it to happen **at some time in the future**. You can follow it with a future tense, as in the following example, though this sounds slightly more formal to me:

> I hope that she will forgive me.

The use of hope already indicates that you are talking about something that may happen in the future, so it is perfectly acceptable to use present simple, especially in informal speech

> I hope [that] she forgives me

---

> a) I sent you that file. (gives idea about my future planned action - **untrue**)

This example uses simple past, which you use to talk about a completed action in the past. Even if you put "I hope that..." in front of it, it is still clear that you are talking about something that, if it did happen at all, happened in the past.

> b) Tomorrow I first go to the temple and then to the office. ( future plans)

This is an example of using simple present tense after a time word (tomorrow) to describe something that  will happen in the future. You will find more about this usage [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/present-simple-intermediate).

You can find more ways to talk about future plans [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/intermediate-grammar/future-plans).

---

Note that the word **wish** indicates that you are talking about an **[irrealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood)** situation (one that is not likely to happen). In such cases, you **must** use the correct tense and then [backshift](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) it (or use the subjunctive **were** for the be-verb, even if there is a time-word.

> You **are** here - *present*
>   I wish you **were** here- *present, subjunctive*
>   You **will** come - *future*
>   I wish you **would** come - *future, backshifted*

---

Note that, in English, you normally only use a capital letter for the first word in the sentence and for proper nouns.

Comment: Thank for the answer JavalLatte... If I say "I Send you that file" is that ok. Does it explain my future plans

Comment: The sentence "I send you that file" is not OK because it does not give any clues that you are talking about the future, I don't see any time word, or anything to indicates that it's a plan. You could say "The plan is that I **send** you the file, then you **make** the changes and **send** it back to me". That's a plan: you can tell because it's got the word **plan** in it.  Or "Tomorrow I **send** you the file and you **return** it to me by Friday".  **Tomorrow** makes it clear that you are talking about a future plan.

Answer (score 1):

*I send you that file* will not normally be interpreted as future meaning, unless the context makes that clear.

So, if you begin a conversation with *I send you that file*, it is incoherent. It can't be present (the "present simple" doesn't have that meaning for most verbs); it is unlikely to be habitual/timeless, because that doesn't make sense with respect to a particular file; and it won't be interpreted as future without some specific context.

But if somebody says *What's the first thing you do when you get into work tomorrow?* it is quite natural to reply *I send you that file*. The future reference has already been established, and the question has use the present simple to refer to it, so you can do so in the answer.

Your example b) is fine.